# Cannot receive notification in "oppo A37" android device

Tags: android, android-notifications

In oppo and vivo device I only get notifications in debug mode. Once I removed it from debug mode, it stop receiving notification. This happens for my own application only. For other applications it works fine. But the thing is it works fine with other devices

Comment: This device have google play Services installed in it?

Comment: reply from their page try this
 "We suggest to put your applications into whitelist to receive notifications. To do that, open applications > Tap on multitask key to show running applications > Swipe your finger down to lock the application (You should see a lock icon in the application, indication that application is already whitelisted)"

Hope this helps.

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar Google play services is there

Answer (score 0):

To receive notification in Oppo device follow below steps

1. You can go to SECURITY CENTRE - PRIVATE PERMISSION - STARTUP MANAGER - add App to the STARTUP APPS ALLOWED
2. Go to SETTING - ADDITIONAL SETTING - APPLICATION MANAGEMENT - AUTOMATIC CLEANING -TURN OFF AUTOMATIC CLEANING
3. Go to SETTING - BATTERY - OTHERS - choose the app that you want to keep notification - turn off FREEZE BACKGROUND APPS
4. SETTING - NOTIFICATION AND STATUS BAR - MANAGEMENT NOTIFICATION - choose the apps - turn on PRIORITY NOTIFICATION
5. SETTING - BATTERY->Low Power Mode turn Off